# ApplicationInsights not sending all Events to Azure

Tags: azure, events, azure-application-insights

I'm trying to send Events from a simple console application to azure, the Events show up in the ApplicationInsights search in VisualStudio but around the first half won't show up in portal.azure.com.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TelemetryClient telemetry = new TelemetryClient();
        telemetry.InstrumentationKey = 
        telemetry.Context.User.Id = Environment.UserName;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {

            var eve = new EventTelemetry();
            eve.Name = "Test4";
            eve.Metrics["SomeMetric"] = i;
            eve.Properties["SomeProperty"] = i.ToString();
            telemetry.TrackEvent(eve);
            telemetry.Flush();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(300);
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you waited few minutes for events to show up in the portal? They typically arrive in under 5 mins, but could be delayed.

Also since you haven't configured channel, the default `InMemoryChannel` will be used - it won't retry sending events to backend if some temp error occurs. `ServerTelemetryChannel` does retry etc. Can you try with `ServerTelemetryChannel`.

```
var serverTelemetryChannel = new ServerTelemetryChannel();
serverTelemetryChannel.Initialize(TelemetryConfiguration.Active);
TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryChannel = serverTelemetryChannel;
```

You can just do a `Flush` and sleep outside the for loop, no need to flush in every iteration.

Comment: Could you explain that a little further? I looked up the ServerTelemetryChannel but am not quite sure on how to implement it. Also if you know how to add the applicationinsights.config manually, that would be great. I waited for it a lot and it seems very strange, as it is very inconsistent.

Comment: What I mean with strange in detail is for example it working when it is in the main function, but as soon as i create a method, using the telemetry etc. to create and track the event, it will work sometime but other times not.

Comment: I updated answer with how to use ServerTelemetryChannel. This should be done right before your for loop.